# Counting and showing only rows whom only have 1 result in specific column

Tags: postgresql

There are 3 tables, and i want to show only those who have result and record in one sport but have never competed ad any other sport. How am I supposed to do the counting?

```
SELECT p.ID, p.name
FROM people p, results r, sports s
WHERE r.result=s.record
  AND p.ID=r.peopleID
  AND r.sportID=s.ID
GROUP BY p.ID
HAVING COUNT(r.sportID) = 1;
```

Comment: That query looks pretty good. What problem do you have with it?

Comment: It shows people who have result in more that one sport that is sportID
so the count(r.sportID) is more than 1 somehow

Comment: How do you tell the sports apart? By `sportid`? If yes, then `COUNT(DISTINCT r.sportid)` should do the trick for you.